# Accessing user uri scheme in models.py in Django web app

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

In `models.py` of my Django app, I have written a custom `Storage` class called `OverwriteStorage`. It's purpose is to upload and get static objects from a 3rd party storage bucket I use (Azure).

Among other things, this custom storage class defines a method called `url`, whereby:

```
def url(self, name):
    """
    Returns the URL where the contents of the file referenced by name can
    be accessed.
    """
    url = '%s/%s/%s' % ('http://example.blob.core.windows.net','mypictures', name)
    return url
```

This method essentially returns the locations of static objects uploaded on the Azure storage blob.

My question is, **is there a way to access the http-protocol scheme** of the user accessing the storage class? My Django web app accepts both `http` and `https` protocols, and I want to append the relevant protocol to the url this method returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct solution here is to just use the protocol-relative URLs, as described in [rfc3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2):

```
return '%s/%s/%s' % ('//example.blob.core.windows.net', 'mypictures', name)
```